# Google Sheets: Menu Item to Hyperlink Phone Number

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to create a menu item that will format a basic number into a hyperlinked phone number. I used to have this code run automatically in the onEdit(), but that never seemed to work reliably. It would only run some of the time.

When I run the following code with the click of the menu item...

```
    function onOpen() {
      var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
      // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
      ui.createMenu('Bedrock')
          .addItem('Hyperlink Phone', 'menuHyperLinkPhone')
          .addToUi();
    }
    
    function menuHyperLinkPhone() {
      SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
      
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var activeCell = ss.getActiveCell();
      var num = activeCell.getValue.toString();
    
      if (num.length == 0){
        ss.toast("Length is 0.")
        return;
      }
    
      if (num.indexOf("ctrlq.org") !== -1) {
        return;
      }
        
      if (num.length == 10) {
        ss.toast("Length is 10.")
        activeCell.setValue('=HYPERLINK("https://ctrlq.org/call/'+e.value+'","'+FormatPhoneNumber(num.value)+'")');
      }
        
      if (num.length > 10) {
        ss.toast("Length is greater than 10.")
        activeCell.setValue('=HYPERLINK("https://ctrlq.org/call/'+num.substring(0,10)+'","'+FormatPhoneNumber(num.value)+'")');
      }
    }

function FormatPhoneNumber(number) {

  var num = number.toString();
  var length = num.length;

  if(num.length == 0){
    return num;
  }

  if(num.length == 10){
    var areacode = num.substring(0,3)
    var prefix = num.substring(3,6)
    var lastfour = num.substring(6,10)

    num = "("+areacode+") "+prefix+"-"+lastfour;

    return num;

  }

  if(num.length > 10){
    var areacode = num.substring(0,3)
    var prefix = num.substring(3,6)
    var lastfour = num.substring(6,10)
    var extension = num.substring(10)

    num = "("+areacode+") "+prefix+"-"+lastfour+" ("+extension+")";

    return num;

  }

}
```

...I get:

TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined

Comment: This line `activeCell.getValue.toString();` should be this `activeCell.getValue().toString();`

Answer (score 1):

I corrected some extra properties... such as num.value, e.value, .toString

```
  function onOpen() {
      var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
      // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
      ui.createMenu('Bedrock')
          .addItem('Hyperlink Phone', 'menuHyperLinkPhone')
          .addToUi();
    }
    
    function menuHyperLinkPhone() {
      SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
      
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var activeCell = ss.getActiveCell();
      var num = activeCell.getValue().toString();
    
      if (num.length == 0){
        ss.toast("Length is 0.")
        return;
      }
    
      if (num.indexOf("ctrlq.org") !== -1) {
        return;
      }
        
      if (num.length == 10) {
        console.log(num)
        console.log(typeof num)
        ss.toast("Length is 10.")
        activeCell.setValue('=HYPERLINK("https://ctrlq.org/call/'+num+'","'+FormatPhoneNumber(num)+'")');
      }
        
      if (num.length > 10) {
        ss.toast("Length is greater than 10.")
        activeCell.setValue('=HYPERLINK("https://ctrlq.org/call/'+num.substring(0,10)+'","'+FormatPhoneNumber(num)+'")');
      }
    }

function FormatPhoneNumber(number) {

  var num = number;
  var length = num.length;

  if(length == 0){
    return num;
  }

  if(length == 10){
    var areacode = num.substring(0,3)
    var prefix = num.substring(3,6)
    var lastfour = num.substring(6,10)

    num = "("+areacode+") "+prefix+"-"+lastfour;

    return num;

  }

  if(length > 10){
    var areacode = num.substring(0,3)
    var prefix = num.substring(3,6)
    var lastfour = num.substring(6,10)
    var extension = num.substring(10)

    num = "("+areacode+") "+prefix+"-"+lastfour+" ("+extension+")";

    return num;

  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks. This solved it. I am not a coder; this was hacked together from examples. Thanks again!